# PHP code not working properly after first echo function

Tags: php

I've been trying to create a web application that functions like a library system, and I am currently working on building the table that will display all books in the system. However, after I close the first echo statement to start building the table in HTML, the app seems to just stop seeing it as code and prints the rest of the PHP code to the screen.

Here is the code in question:

```
<?php
        $db = mysqli_connect('34.224.99.227','root','opendoor','library')
            or die ('Could not connect to database');

        $result = mysqli_query($db,'SELECT * FROM book');

        echo '<table id="table_id" class="display">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ISBN</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>';

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['isbn'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['title'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['author'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['description'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['status'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }

        echo '</tbody></table>';

        mysqli_close($db);
    ?>
```

And here is the corresponding web page output:

> ISBN Title Author Description Status '; while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo ''; echo '' . $row['isbn'] . ''; echo '' . $row['title'] . ''; echo '' . $row['author'] . ''; echo '' . $row['description'] . ''; echo '' . $row['status'] . ''; echo ''; } echo ''; mysqli_close($db); ?>

I'm obviously not too well-versed in PHP, so I'm at a loss as to what the problem could be.

Comment: opening php tags? *.php file name? running on a server with php?

Comment: Added the full php section. It is a php file. It's a local file right now.

Comment: There are no errors in that code you supply

Comment: local file, but you are running a web server and php? accessing the file via `http://(local ip address)` with a browser?

Comment: Do you have HTML tags for `html`, `head`, `body` DOCTYPE etc. anywhere in there?

Comment: I know. That's what I don't understand. I've repeatedly checked to make sure the syntax is right, and it matches every other similar piece of code I've seen.

Comment: Make sure you have installed apache and php and run it like http://localhost/yourfile.php. You can install xampp or wamp and put the file in htdocs and run it as http://localhost/yourfile.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with the settings of my LAMP stack, I realized that I had apparently configured it with PHP 5 in mind, while I had downloaded PHP 7. Once I fixed the discrepancy, everything worked as intended. Thanks for help nonetheless.